# Verifying Which Ports Are Listening on the Remote server using NMAP

Tags: centos6

Using redhat, What's the good command to verify port that for example google server is listening?

Comment: I think I speak for everyone here when I say, "huh?"

Comment: You want to port scan remote host you don't control ? It can be seen as hacking attempt.

Comment: any other suggestion please?..If you don't have the answer. please don't waist your time by leaving a comment!!! Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "huh!?"

Comment: Could you tell me why you think is off-topic ? because "Huh!?" does not really make sense to me. Read the title and tell me what is off the topic!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this command :

```
nmap -v -A www.xyz.com 
nmap -v -A ipaddress
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/

Comment: Ashish..at least someone who understood my question "...sigh.."

Comment: @KingKong you are right but this is not right place to discuss how site works but you can contribute by giving your opinion at right place :)

Comment: Thank you and I'll take your comment in consideration, but what makes you  think it's about site?

Comment: @KingKong what makes you think it's about site? – Means ??  I don't get

Comment: is telnet a site?

Comment: telnet is command in linux

Comment: really?  sigh...